# What are all the possible combinations of information needed to write a linear equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

In order for someone to write a linear equation, they need some information about the line. For example, here are a few info combinations where writing a linear equation is possible:

1. Slope + Y-intercept (solution: plug in values)
2. Slope + 1 coordinate point that the line goes through (solution: increase or decrease coordinate by slope value until x = 0 to find y-intercept)
3. 2 coordinate points (solution: find slope and do the same as step 2 to find y-intercept)
4. 1 coordinate point and the equation of a line that's parallel/perpendicular to the other line (**Parallel solution**: plug in the slope of the other line and repeat step 2 to find y-intercept. **Perpendicular Solution**: get negative reciprocal of the slope of the other line and repeat step 2 to find y-intercept)

Is there any other info or info combinations that could be involved? This is a little hard to explain so if it's unclear, please tell me in the comments.

Comment: I like to give my students a graph of a line and try to work out the equation of the line given the graph. Essentially the same as using two points to find the equation, but maybe they can use the y-intercept to make the problem easier, and they can estimate the slope from the graph to check their answer.

Comment: The following works for lines not through the origin and not horizontal or vertical. Let $a$ be the $x$-intercept and $b$ be the $y$-intercept [i.e. points $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ are on the line] Then an equation is $x/a+y/b=1.$ I've heard of this called the "intercept-intercept" form.